# Cron jobs in wordpress environment without utilizing wordpress scheduler

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I want to setup a cron job on my server (via crontab) that hits a script which requires the wordpress-environment to be loaded in order to work.

My current solution looks like this: I’m triggering a php script which requires 'wp-load.php' and kicks things off via triggering a hook using
`do_action('stuff_that_happens_when_crontab_hits')` to which the actual code that needs to be executed listen within a `add_action('stuff_that_happens_when_crontab_hits', 'the stuff')` of course. I also disabled the cron implementation of wordpress `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`

The crontab entry looks like this:

```
0 * * * * /var/www/wp/mywpcron.php
```

This is the file that gets hit by crontab:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
if (php_sapi_name() !== "cli")
        return;
require 'wp-load.php';
do_action('stuff_that_happens_when_crontab_hits')`;
```

Does this seem legit or am I overseeing any negative repercussions? Any input would be grandly appreciated!

Comment: i think wp cron going to check all the time page loads .... https://www.chriswiegman.com/2012/04/stop-wp-cron-wordpress-cron-jobs-from-firing-on-every-page-load/

Comment: oh yes, i forgot to mention that i don't utilize wordpress' cron implementation, i updated my question, thanks for pointing that out.